# JSR223 reg ex does not work with \\

Tags: jmeter

in JSR223 I am able to remove whatever is between

```
<Notes>  and </Notes>:
 <Notes>{
 "abc":12,
 "xyz": "Success",
}</Notes>
```

with this regex -->

```
str1 = str1.replaceAll("<Notes[^>]*>([^<]*)<\\/Notes>", "<Notes><\\/Notes>");
```

but when i have: -->

```
  <Notes>{
   "abc":D:\\xyz\\12.txt,
   "xyz": "Success",
  }</Notes>
```

that reg ex does not work  because now I have \ to worry about and not sure how to incorporate that.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it "doesn't work"? It should work for whatever is between Notes tags

[image: JMeter Groovy Replace]

So it might be the case you are incorrectly referring the result or it is been overwritten somewhere else.

You can try the following things just in case:

1. You [don't need to escape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) `/` in the regex.
2. You can try amending your regex to something like `<Notes>[\\s\\S]*?</Notes>`
3. Make sure you're using [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) language

Comment: I found this solution which I think will work on both cases now   <Notes[^>]*>([^<]*)", "<Notes>